# Solve an inequality finding the upper bound

Tags: self-study, nonparametric, integral, norm, absolute-value

Suppose that there exists a constant $C$ such that the following relation
holds for all $G$:
\begin{equation*}
    \vert T(F)-T(G) \vert \le C \sup_y \vert F(y)-G(y) \vert
\end{equation*}
Suppose that $|Y|\le M < \infty$. Show that $T(F)=\int ydF(y)$ satisfies the previous relation.

In particular we are in the setting of nonparametric statistics. So T(F) is a statistical functional. F(y) and G(y) are the real cumulative distribution function that we would like to estimate.

It is an exercise in the second chapter of "all of nonparametric statistics" by Wassermann.

I have difficulties setting up this problem and understanding how to solve it. Can somebody help please?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know I should provide more information about where I am stuck but the fact is that I do not know how to start in the first place!

Comment: It is exactly the question asked in the book!

Comment: It is the beginning of Nonparametric statistics and I am doing these exercises for training. I understand the question but I don't know how to solve it since I am not a mathematic student. I have some difficulties with this kind of exercises.

Comment: About your questions above: Yes I think you are right! As a matter of fact the book itself do not specify the interval of the integral. But yes I think you are right.

Comment: Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

That integral function $T$ is an expression for the mean (or expectation value) of $Y$ when it follows the distribution $F$. See the bullet point 'Formulas in terms of CDF' on Wikipedia's [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties) about the expectation value

> - **Formulas in terms of CDF**: If $F(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function of a random variable $X$ then $$E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x dF(x),$$ where the values on both sides are well defined or not well defined simultaneously, and the integral is taken in the sense of Lebesgue-Stieltjes. As a consequence of integration by parts as applied to this representation of $E[X]$, it can be proved that $$E[X] = \int_0^\infty (1-F(x)) dx - \int_{-\infty}^0 F(x) dx$$

If your variable has finite bounds $M \leq \infty$ then you do not integrate from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and you can use

$$T(F) = E[X_F] = \int_0^M (1-F(x)) dx - \int_{-M}^0 F(x) dx$$

and the same for $G$ if it has the same bounds

$$T(G) = E[X_G] = \int_0^M (1-G(x)) dx - \int_{-M}^0 G(x) dx$$

The difference can be expressed as

$$T(F)-T(G) = \int_0^M (G(x)-F(x)) dx - \int_{-M}^0 F(x)-G(x) dx$$

To continue see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Inequalities and in particular the inequality for the upper and lower bounds in terms of the minimum and maximum value of the integrand.

Comment: @Bibi is this answer useful?